# How to create a factory that returns anonymous classes that implement a generic interface

Tags: generics, typescript, type-safety, ngrx

We are using ngrx with Angular/TypeScript. To add some type safety to Actions, we created the following

```
export interface TypedAction<T> extends Action {
    type: string;
    payload: T;
}

export class ExtensionRegistrationAction implements TypedAction<ExtensionRegistrationPayload> {
    readonly type = ExtensionActionTypes.REGISTER_EXTENSION;
    constructor(public payload: ExtensionRegistrationPayload) {}
}

export class ExtensionRegistrationSucceededAction implements TypedAction<void> {
    readonly type = ExtensionActionTypes.REGISTER_EXTENSION_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: void) {}
}

export class ExtensionRegistrationFailedAction implements TypedAction<{messageCode: string}> {
    readonly type = ExtensionActionTypes.REGISTER_EXTENSION_FAILURE;
    constructor(public payload: {messageCode: string}) {}
}


export type ExtensionActions = ExtensionRegistrationAction
    | ExtensionRegistrationFailedAction
    | ExtensionRegistrationSucceededAction;

// The above lets us do the following
export function appExtensionsReducer(state: AppExtensionState = initialAppExtensionsState,
                                     action: ExtensionActions): AppExtensionState {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ExtensionActionTypes.REGISTER_EXTENSION: 
            const registerAction = action as ExtensionRegistrationAction;
            return {
                registrations: state.registrations.concat(registerAction.payload)
            };
        // Handle other actions...
        default: {
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

To get rid of the boiler place code, I thought I could create a function that generates those classes.

```
export function createTypedActionConstructor<T>(type: string): TypedAction<T> {
    return class TypedActionImpl implements TypedAction<T> {
        readonly type = type;
        constructor(public payload: T) {}
    }
}
```

But I get an error because what I'm returning is the class that implements TypedAction, not the instance. The error says:

> TS2322 Type 'typeof TypedActionImpl' is not assignable to type 'TypedAction'. Property 'type' is missing.

**What I did get working**

The following code gets around the problem by requiring two declarations, one for the interface that implements `T` and one for a factory function that creates that type `T`. The problem is that it doesn't help that much with boiler plate code bloat.

```
export function createTypedActionFactory<T>(type: string): (payload: T) => TypedAction<T> {
    return function(payload: T): TypedAction<T> {
        return {type, payload};
    }
}
// Now to create an action I need the two statements
export interface ExtensionRegistrationAction extends TypedAction<ExtensionRegistrationPayload> {}
export const createExtensionRegistrationAction = createTypedActionFactory<ExtensionRegistrationPayload>(
    ExtensionActionTypes.REGISTER_EXTENSION);
```

**Question**
Is it impossible to return a dynamic implementation of a generic class from TypeScript?

Comment: Did you try returning a `typeof`: `export function createTypedActionConstructor<T>(type: string): typeof TypedAction<T> {}`

Comment: I did... that is not even syntactically valid

Answer (score 2):

should be:

```
export function createTypedActionConstructor<T>(type: string): { new (payload: T): TypedAction<T> } {
    ...
}
```

---

#### Edit

Another option is to add multiple function signatures:

```
export function createTypedActionConstructor(type: ExtensionActionTypes.REGISTER_EXTENSION_FAILURE): { new (payload: {messageCode: string}): ExtensionRegistrationFailedAction };
export function createTypedActionConstructor(type: ExtensionActionTypes.REGISTER_EXTENSION_SUCCESS): { new (payload: void): ExtensionRegistrationSucceededAction };
...
```

Comment: This is great, the only problem is that I had been doing the following: `export type ExtensionActions = ExtensionRegistrationAction
    | ExtensionRegistrationFailedAction
    | ExtensionRegistrationSucceededAction;` which this method does not allow. It also doesn't allow me to cast something to be of that type: Do you know of a way around that?

Comment: Check my revised answer