# How do you type a class decorator factory?

Tags: typescript

I have found countless threads, none of which quite seems to match my use case *and* version of TypeScript (2.8.1). I've tried a few incarnations of extremely basic class decorator factories with no luck.

```
type Constructable<T> = { new (): T }

function decoratorFactory<T> (): (Base: Constructable<T>) => Constructable<T> {
  return function decorator (Base: Constructable<T>): Constructable<T> {
    return class extends Base { // line 5
      constructor () {
        super()
        console.log('in constructor')
      }
    }
  }
}

@decoratorFactory()
class Example {}
```

```
index.ts(5,5): error TS2322: Type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'Constructable<T>'.
  Type '(Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'T'.
index.ts(5,26): error TS2509: Base constructor return type 'T' is not a class or interface type.
```

The first error can be removed with a type annotation, though I don't understand why it is required, and it does nothing for the second error.

```
type Constructable<T> = { new (): T }

function decoratorFactory<T> (): (Base: Constructable<T>) => Constructable<T> {
  return function decorator (Base: Constructable<T>): Constructable<T> {
    return class extends Base {
      constructor () {
        super()
        console.log('in constructor')
      }
    } as Constructable<T>
  }
}

@decoratorFactory()
class Example {}
```

```
index.ts(5,26): error TS2509: Base constructor return type 'T' is not a class or interface type.
```

I've seen some examples use `T extends <some empty interface>`, but that fixes nothing for me:

```
interface ClassOrInterface {}
type Constructable<T> = { new (): T }

function decoratorFactory<T extends ClassOrInterface> (): (Base: Constructable<T>) => Constructable<T> {
  return function decorator (Base: Constructable<T>): Constructable<T> {
    return class extends Base {
      constructor () {
        super()
        console.log('in constructor')
      }
    } as Constructable<T>
  }
}

@decoratorFactory()
class Example {}
```

```
index.ts(6,26): error TS2509: Base constructor return type 'T' is not a class or interface type.
```

I've seen answers that suggest you can [return a constructor function instead of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43000982/how-to-create-a-factory-that-returns-anonymous-classes-that-implement-a-generic). I've seen answers that use `new () => T` and `{ new (): T }` interchangeably. I've seen [issues that use cast syntax that is now prohibited](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4890). I've seen answers that just [return the constructor that was passed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45160341/how-do-you-type-a-class-decorator-in-typescript?rq=1), instead of a new constructor/class.

How can I do what I want?